# How to find my rails path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I have rails 3 installed with rvm and today i tried to add the alias 'subl' (from Sublime Text  2) to use on terminal. The problem is the 'subl' command works and i think i messed up with the paths, because the rails command is not found anymore.
How do I find the correct rails path and fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup. If you're using rvm, it will probably be

```
~/.rvm/gems/<ruby version that you use>/bin/rails
```

If you're using the system ruby, then have a look in the gems folder of wherever your ruby install is, and add that to the path. On windows, the ruby installer generally puts it in

```
C:\Ruby
```

Or something like that. On Mac, the default system ruby is

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```